# Use update_attributes with value entered by user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What I'm trying to do is update only one value of my object. I was able to do this part when I put the value myself but I am trying to have the user enter the value he wants and then using that value update my attribute.

```
<td><%= text_field(:referent, :titre, size: 20) %>
<%= link_to(referent.titre,  referent_path(referent, "referent[titre]" => "Changed"), :method => :put) %></td>
```

Right now I just have the value "Changed" in it and that works it changes the value of my attribute `titre` but I can't figure out how to take the value from the  `text_field` and put it at the place of "Changed"

This is my `update` method

```
def update
  @referents = Referent.find(params[:id])
    if @referents.update_attributes(referent_params)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are submitting the form results, but instead linking to another page and setting the param for titre in the url. Try this:

```
<%=form_for @referents do |f| %>
<%=f.label :titre%>
<%=f.text_field :titre, size: 20%>
<%=f.submit%>
```

Comment: To expound on why you can't figure out how to change the "Changed" value to the value of the text box: What you end up having is hard HTML that isn't dynamic. You could keep your same setup and instead use JS to update that param in the link as you type, but  I wholly recommend against that. The form_for @object is the 'rails' way to modify model data. When you get a chance you should check out simple_form from platformatec, They take rails forms up a level.